# For an integrable function, does there exist a sequence of partitions with this property.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Assume you have the measurespace $([a,b],\mathcal{B}([a,b],l)$, where $l$ is the Lebesgue measure. Assume also you have an integrable function $f [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on the measure space.

For a partition of $[a,b]$, $\Pi=\{t_0=a<t_2,\cdots,t_n=b\}$, define

$$I(\Pi)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}f(t_i)\cdot1_{\{x: |f(x)|<\infty\}}(t_i)(t_{i+1}-t_i).$$

For an arbitrary sequence of partitions, $\Pi_n$, with $\max_{i \in \{0,\cdots n-1\}}(t_{i+1}-t_i)\rightarrow 0$, I am quite sure it is not the case that

$$\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}I(\Pi_n)=\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}I(\Pi_n)=\int_{[a,b]}f(x)dx.$$

But I am wondering what happens if we may choose a special sequence so that it holds, so what I am wondering is:

**Case 1:**

Does there exist a sequence of partitions where the above equality holds?

**Case 2:**
If for a partition $\Pi$ we define
$$f_{\Pi}(t)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}f(t_i)\cdot1_{\{x: |f(x)|<\infty\}}(t_i)1_{x \in [t_i,t_{i+1})}(t),$$

and we still assume that $f$ is integrable, does there exist a sequence of partitions $\{\Pi_n\}$ so that

$$\int_{[a,b)}|f(t)-f_{\Pi_n}(t)|dt\rightarrow0?$$

**Case 3**
If we also assume that $f \in L^2([a,b])$, and let $f_\Pi$ be as above, does there exist a sequence of partitions $\{\Pi_n\}$ such that

$$\int_{[a,b)}|f(t)-f_{\Pi_n}(t)|^2dt\rightarrow0?$$

Comment: really neat question! So we're looking for a sequence of partitions that works for **every** integrable $f$, right?

Comment: @Zim No, the sequence can depend on $f$, but if someone is able to find one that holds for every $f$ that would of course be great.

Comment: @Zim Actually I think it is easy to show that a sequence can not hold for every $f$. For instance if the sequence is chosen, let the function be $0$ at the partitions points and $1$ elsewhere, then it is a.e. $1$, but the quantity we're calculate using the paritions is $0$.

Comment: Nice question. It looks like all your question is fine if $f$ is bounded.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen Do you mean that it is true if $f$ is bounded?, if so why? I am not sure we can use dominated convergence here, beacuse I don't think we necessarily have convergence a.e.?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Though that is not my direction, I did overlook some factor.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to find such a partition, and the proof relies mostly on the [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem) . What the Lebesgue theorem says is that for almost every $x \in [a,b]$, $\lim \limits_{r \to 0}  \displaystyle{\frac{1}{2r} \int_{x-r}^{x+r}} |f(t)-f(x)| dt = 0$.

I'll answer directly Case 2, and you can prove Case 3 in a similar way

---

**Hypothesis 1: assume $f$ is bounded**

For $k \ge 1$, $\varepsilon>0$, denote $I_{k, \varepsilon} = \Big\{x \in [a,b]: \quad \forall 0 < r \le \frac{1}{k}, \ \displaystyle{\frac{1}{r} \int_{x-r}^{x+r}} |f(t)-f(x)|dt < \varepsilon\Big\}$. For a given $\varepsilon$, these sets are increasing with $k$, and the Lebesgue differentiation theorem yields that almost every $x$ is in $\bigcup \limits_{k\ge 1} I_{k, \varepsilon}$.

Let us now set $\varepsilon_0$ a final limit for the approximation error (and find a partition that does the deed). We also introduce $\delta>0$, and will try to control the integral precisely everywhere except on a set of measure $\delta$. The value of $\delta$ will be set later.

Let us take $k$ large enough that we have **(Hyp $1$)**: $\mu\Big(\big[a, b \big] \backslash I_{k, \frac{\varepsilon_0}{2(b-a)}}\Big) < \frac{\delta}{2}$. Denoting $\varepsilon_1 = \frac{\varepsilon_0}{2(b-a)}$, we'll choose $x_1 < x_2 < ... < x_n$ in $I_{k, \varepsilon_1}$ such that $\mu\Big( \bigcup \limits_{i=1}^n [x_i, x_i + r[\Big) \ge b-a -  \delta$, where $x_{i+1}> x_i+r$ for all $i$ and $x_n+r > b$.

> *Proof:* We can find $x \in ]a, b] \cap I_{k,\varepsilon_1}$ such that $\mu\big([a,x_1[ \backslash I_{k,\varepsilon_1}\big) \le \frac{\delta}{4}$, by choosing it arbitrarily close to $\inf I_{k,\varepsilon_1}$. By applying the same reasoning with the infimum of $]x_i+r, b] \cap I_{k,\varepsilon_1}$, for $i \ge 1$ we can find $x_{i+1} \in I_{k,\varepsilon_1}$ such that $x_{i+1} > x_i + r$ and $\mu\big([x_i+r, x_{i+1}[ \backslash I_{k,\varepsilon_1}\big) \le \frac{\delta}{2^{i+2}}$, until we find $x_n$ such that $x_n + r > b$. Then since the $[x_i+r, x_{i+1}[$ are distinct, \begin{align*} \mu\Big([a,b] \backslash \bigcup \limits_{i=1}^n [x_i, x_i+r[\Big) & \le  \mu\big(I_{k,\varepsilon_1}\big) + \mu\Big(\big([a,x_1[ \cup \bigcup \limits_{i=1}^{n-1} [x_i+r, x_{i+1}[\big) \backslash I_{k,\varepsilon_1} \\ & = \mu\big(I_{k,\varepsilon_1}\big) + \mu\big([a, x_1[\backslash I_{k,\varepsilon_1}\big) + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n-1} \mu\big([x_i+r, x_{i+1}[ \backslash I_{k,\varepsilon_1}\big) \\ & < \frac{\delta}{2} + \frac{\delta}{4} + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{\delta}{2^{2+i}} \le \delta \end{align*}

Now note that since $x_j \in I_{k,\varepsilon_1}$, by definition of that set, we have $$\forall j, \ \ \forall r \le \frac{1}{k}, \ \displaystyle{\frac{1}{r}\int_{x_j}^{x_j+r}} |f(t)-f(x_j)|dt \le \frac{\varepsilon_0}{2(b-a)} \tag{$\star$}$$

To simplify notations, we are going to keep talking about the last interval as $[x_n, x_n+r[$, which goes further than $b$. Think of it instead as $[x_n, b]$. We denote $$\Pi = \{a, x_1, x_1+r, x_2, x_2+r, ..., x_n, b\}$$ and $f_{\Pi}$ the associated approximation. Using $(\star)$, we get:

$$\displaystyle{\int_{\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^n [x_i, x_i+r[}} |f(t) - f_{\Pi}(t)| \le \mu\big(\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^n [x_i,x_i+r[\big) \cdot \frac{\varepsilon_0}{2(b-a)} \le \frac{\varepsilon_0}{2}$$

Denoting $B = [a,x_1[ \cup \bigcup \limits_{i=1}^{n-1} [x_i+r, x_{i+1}[$, by construction we have $\mu(B) \le \delta$, so $$\displaystyle{\int_B} |f(t) - f_{\Pi}(t)|dt \le 2 ||f||_{\infty} \delta.$$

Thus the total error is $\frac{\varepsilon_0}{2} + 2 ||f||_{\infty} \delta$, and it suffices to take $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon_0}{4 ||f||_{\infty}}$ to find a partition $\Pi$ with $||f - f_{\Pi}||_1 \le \varepsilon_0$.

Comment: There are some sleights of hand in the construction of the partition, I'm ready to answer any questions you may have, in the comments and with modifications in the post

Comment: Also, I'm not fully sure that the unbounded case is straightforward from the bounded one, but I'm on it

Comment: Thank you very much, I have looked through the proof and I can't find any errors, I'll keep going through it to see if everything is clear. Let us know if you are able to do it in the unbounded case aswell.

Comment: I'm sorry about the use of the Vitali covering lemma by the way. It seems to me that 'covering a large part of a set with a large number of intervals $]x-\frac{1}{k}, x+\frac{1}{k}[$' is pretty obvious (I get this feeling because the radius $\frac{1}{k}$ is a constant over all $x$), but I couldn't think of a faster way to do it than hammering Vitali

Comment: I have two minor comments: 1. When you let $x_j'$ be the union of all $x_j$ and all $x_j-1/k$ it may not be that $x_k-1/k$ is ok to use since the interval is open? I guess this is easily fixed by choosing a point above $x_j-1/k$ very close, and closer and closer by a factor of for instance $\delta/4/2^j$? 2. Considering 1., and the fact that sometimething might happen at the endpoints I understand that we need to redifince the radius and that the introduction of $r_j$ is necessary, but why did you introduce $r_j$?, why did you need that when the intervals were disjoint?

Comment: I'm going to clarify the post, but to answer your two questions: when choosing the $x_j'$ among the $x_j - \frac{1}{k}$, it does not matter to change the open intervals into closed intervals since it doesn't change the measure of the union of semi-intervals. I'm not sure if I see your problem with that point, don't hesitate to clarify

Comment: Regarding the 2nd question, I only introduced the endpoints $r_j$ so that we would have a semblance of a partition (albeit incomplete). For a very simple example with $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and $k = 3$, it could be that our $x_j'$ are $\{0.1, 0.25, 0.6, 0.62, 0.9\}$. The idea was to choose$x_1', x_1'+\frac{1}{3}, x_2', x_2+\frac{1}{3}, ...$ as endpoints of your partition, but they aren't ordered (the $[x_j', x_j'+\frac{1}{k}[$ are not disjoint, so not exactly a partition (although you still have 'natural' endpoints - just remove the ones in excess by shortening to remove overlaps, and thus the $r_j$)

Comment: Btw, in my example, you also have a problem with the final endpoint (because $0.9 + \frac{1}{3}>1$, which is something you mentioned in your comment, but which I did not address in my post. It is also a second reason to introduce the $r_j$ (don't have a last endpoint in the (incomplete) partition that is already larger than $b$)

Comment: The reason I asked about $x_j-1/k$ is that we do not know if $x_j-1/k$ is in $I_{k,\epsilon_1}$? Regarding the second point, it says in the Wikipedia article that the intervals we end up with in the Vitaly covering lemma are disjoint, so does not that exclude your example from happening?

Comment: Sorry, I see that when we increase the radius of the open balls in the vitaly covering lemma, we might not keep dijointness.

Comment: You first point is a good question: $x_j - \frac{1}{k}$ may very well **not** be in $I_{k, \varepsilon_1}$. However, since $x_j$ is in $I_{k, \varepsilon_1}$, you know that the integral from $x_j - \frac{1}{k}$ to $x_j + \frac{1}{k}$ is less than $\frac{\varepsilon}{k}$ (I just removed a factor $2$ in the definition of $I_{k, ..}$ btw). That allows you to control the integral on $[x_j', x_j'+\frac{1}{k}[$, for $x_j' \in \{x_j-\frac{1}{k}, x_j\}$

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. But isn't the problem that in one case the integrand is $|f(t)-f(x_j)|$ and in the other case it is $|f(t)-f(x_{j-1/k})|$?, so it is not the same integral? The fact that the integral of the first integrand over $x_j-1/k$ to $x_j+1/k$ is small, does necessarily imply that the second integrand is small over $x_j-1/k$ to $x_j$? Can we control the integral of $|f(t)-f(x_{j-1/k})|$ when $x_{j-1/k}$ is not in $I_{k,\epsilon}$?

Comment: That is a very good remark, sorry for my mistake. I'll try to get rid of Vitali and choose the $x_j'$ in $I_{k,\varepsilon_1}$ "by hand", I'm pretty sure it's possible (informally, choose $x_1$ 'roughly closest' to $a$, then $x_2$ 'roughly the closest possible above $x_1 + \frac{1}{k}$, etc...). Instead of covering with balls and halving them in two semi-intervals

Comment: I awareded you the bounty because it was about to run out tomorrow. Thank you very much for your input, if you are able to solve the problem or discover the unbounded case anytime please let us know.

Comment: Sorry for the very late edit, I changed the answer according to what we were discussing in the comments